# how to read specific dataLayer obj in gtm custom template

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

when I try below to access datalayer in custom template using copyFromWindow,

```
`if (queryPermission('access_globals', 'readwrite', 'dataLayer')) {
     const dataLayer = copyFromWindow('dataLayer');
      log('dataLayer =', dataLayer.length);
}`

output :` `[{"gtm.start":1631682185554,"event":"gtm.js","gtm.uniqueEventId":3}]
```

I  am trying to access say 13th item in the dataLayer array I can get the value by doing dataLayer[13].segments in console. But unable to figure out how to do this in the custom template

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, can I ask what your use case is for this? Because at runtime you have no way of knowing what actually is at position 13 (or any other given index),  so this would be useless to extract any specific values.

Comment: Okay, I tried this, and in the custom template it works exactly as in the console - dataLayer[<index>].<property>. Of course due to the caveat in my first comment, you might not know if the expected property is actually there, so you'D need to include some error handling.

Comment: @Erike Pierstorff In console I can do a null check and find the property by index but in custom template, when I try to access dataLayer using the copyFromWindow, its not returning the complete dataLayer

Comment: I literally just did that. If I log the complete datalayer I get the same output as you, but if I address a specific index I can retrieve the information therein without a problem.

Comment: you mean somthing like this  --> const dataLayer = copyFromWindow('dataLayer[13]');